# Convert Double in "d HH:mm"

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a formula that generates a table of 100 rows and 4 columns, the last column returns me certain numbers of hours, I wanted this value to be expressed as "d HH: mm"

I try Timespan, but don't work

```
DT5.Rows.Add(I, Format((100 * LA()) / I, "#,##0.0#"), Format(((I * VPR()) / 100), "#,##0.0#"), (((DM() / ((I * VPR()) / 1000))).ToString("d HH:mm")))
```

The last part (((DM() / ((I * VPR()) / 1000))).ToString("d HH:mm")), should return something in "d HH:mm"

Comment: The "don't work" error is a tough one. What are `LA()`, `VPR()`, and `DM()`? Can you show the code where you tried creating a `TimeSpan`?

Comment: Can't tell if @EdPlunkett is trying to be funny or not but... What all did you try in regards to `Timespan`? Can you elaborate a little more as well?

Comment: `LA(), VPR(), and DM()` They are given by the program.  My last try with `TimeSpan`: `TimeSpan.FromHours(((DM() / ((I * VPR()) / 1000))).ToString("d hh:mm"))`

Comment: @AlexNunes In the debugger, when you put in a breakpoint and stop in the debugger at runtime, what value is returned by `((DM() / ((I * VPR()) / 1000))` and what value is returned by `TimeSpan.FromHours(((DM() / ((I * VPR()) / 1000)))`?

Comment: Your format string isn't valid for a TimeSpan.. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#other-characters. You need to escape characters that aren't format specifiers - i.e. the space and the colon, e.g. `"d\\ hh\\:mm"`

Comment: Not sure if you find it useful but conversion between datetime and double is recommended by the built-in functions  [ToOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tooadate?view=netframework-4.8) and [FromOADate](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.datetime.fromoadate?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't format a float and expect the formatter to figure out that it was a TimeSpan you wanted. So you should create a TimeSpan from `TimeSpan.FromHours(Double)`

Then, when using a space in the format, you need to escape it. A comment was made about this but it used C# syntax and a double backslash `\\`, while your code lacked the C# line termination character `;`. I'll just guess and treat your question as VB.NET.

You can escape the space, or you can build the string from the individual properties of the TimeSpan. Both options are presented below

```vb
Dim elapsed = TimeSpan.FromHours(DM() / (I * VPR() / 1000))

Dim formattedTimeSpan = $"{elapsed:d\ h\:mm}"
formattedTimeSpan = $"{elapsed.Days} {elapsed.Hours}:{elapsed.Minutes}"
```

You can also make your code more readable using [$ string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/special-characters/interpolated)

```vb
DT5.Rows.Add(
    I,
    $"{100 * LA() / I:#,##0.0#}",
    $"{I * VPR() / 100:#,##0.0#}",
    formattedTimeSpan)
```

or if you still prefer one line,

```vb
DT5.Rows.Add(I, $"{100 * LA() / I:#,##0.0#}", $"{I * VPR() / 100:#,##0.0#}", $"{TimeSpan.FromHours(DM() / (I * VPR() / 1000)):d\ h\:mm}")
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, grateful.